# Timeline Slicer Excel 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, excel

hoping someone can help

I'm trying to call a timeline slicer value in vba so I can control other slicers. I have managed it from cells but I was wondering if it can be controlled by my master slicer

```
Sub Slicer_Time_Change()

Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date

startDate = Range("A1") 'Set slicer 1 start date as slicer selection instead
endDate = Range("B1")    'Set slicer 1 End date as slicer selection instead


ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date1").TimelineState. _
SetFilterDateRange startDate, endDate

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches )("NativeTimeline_Date2").TimelineState. _
SetFilterDateRange startDate, endDate
```

End Sub

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer this one myself!

```
Sub Slicer_Time_Change()

'Gets data from master slicer selection
Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date1")
'Puts into cell
Cells(1, 1) = cache.TimelineState.startDate
Cells(1, 2) = cache.TimelineState.endDate


Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date

startDate = Range("A1")
endDate = Range("B1")
'Takes data from cell and controls other slicers with date range
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date2").TimelineState. _
SetFilterDateRange startDate, endDate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Your answer helped but I needed this triggered when the master slicer changed. Unfortunately slicers have no events, but the PivotTables they impact do. The code below will update all other timeline slicers when the master slicer changes which, in turn, changes its PivotTable, which can then be used to trigger changes to all other slicers.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)

'   Description:Update Timeline Slicers from Master Slicer
'   Inputs:     Sh          PivotTable's worksheet
'               Target      PivotTable being changed/updated
'   Outputs:    *None
'   Requisites: *None
'   Example:    *None - This is an event handler found in ThisWorkbook module

'     Date   Ini Modification
'   10/19/16 CWH Initial Development

'   Declarations
    Const cRoutine      As String = "Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate"
    Dim oSlicer         As SlicerCache      'Current Slicer
    Const cSlicer       As Long = 1         'Master Slicer
    Dim dStartDate      As Date             'Start Date
    Dim dEndDate        As Date             'End Date
    Dim bCleared        As Boolean          'Filter Cleared Flag
    Dim bEvents         As Boolean          'Events Enabled Flag

'   Error Handling Initialization
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'   Prevent cascading events
    bEvents = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

'   Get Master Slicer's dates
    Set oSlicer = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(cSlicer)
    bCleared = oSlicer.FilterCleared
    If Not bCleared Then
        With oSlicer.TimelineState
            dStartDate = .FilterValue1
            dEndDate = .FilterValue2
        End With
    End If

'   Set All other Timeline Slicer Dates
    For Each oSlicer In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches
        If oSlicer.SlicerCacheType = xlTimeline And _
           oSlicer.Index <> cSlicer Then
            If bCleared Then _
                oSlicer.ClearAllFilters Else _
                    oSlicer.TimelineState.SetFilterDateRange _
                        StartDate:=dStartDate, EndDate:=dEndDate
        End If
    Next

ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Is = 0:                            'Do nothing
        Case Is = 9:                            'Do Nothing Master Slicer Missing
        Case Else:
            Select Case MsgBox(Prompt:=Err.Description, _
                               Buttons:=vbAbortRetryIgnore, _
                               Title:=cRoutine, _
                               HelpFile:=Err.HelpFile, _
                               Context:=Err.HelpContext)
                Case Is = vbAbort:  Stop: Resume    'Debug mode - Trace
                Case Is = vbRetry:  Resume          'Try again
                Case Is = vbIgnore:                 'End routine
            End Select
    End Select
'   Clean up: Resume responding to events
    Application.EnableEvents = bEvents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    If Target = "TopElementOfSum" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date1").TimelineState.SetFilterDateRange ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date").TimelineState.StartDate, ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date").TimelineState.EndDate
        'NativeTimeline_Date1 to numer slidera w systemie nie jego nazwa, kiedys dlugo sie z tym jebalem bo nie wiedzialem co jest 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Works for me, just SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date") refers to internal numbering of Time Lines, no names of them.